# Does God as depicted in Jewish/Christian/Muslim sources have any weaknesses?

Tags: warfare, gods, mythology

I've heard a few stories, like Left Beyond Quest and the plot of the game Messiah, in which humanity attempts to fight/conquer Heaven and Hell. The general consensus is that, since there aren't any omnipotent or omniscient demons that Christians believe in, it should be doable to conquer Hell. However, when it comes to fighting or conquering Heaven, the big obstacle is God.

So this is my question: do any Jewish, Christian, or Muslim documents reveal any weaknesses that could be exploited? And if not, are there any logical weaknesses to such a being, which could be extrapolated from what IS known?

(not looking for cynical/atheist answers about him not existing)

Comment: Since you are looking at canonically framed answers, this sounds like a better fit for the religion dedicated SE portals.

Comment: I'm not sure how "omnipotent" and "omniscient" will have weaknesses. It's basically another version of "If God is all powerful, can He make a boulder that He cannot lift?"

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, I agree with your, but I don't think that question of ways to overthrow god and invade Heaven would be nicely answered on religion SE portals. It is realy would be better kept here not to be taken too seriosly

Comment: Idea: Use Metatron as the "Head Boss" of Heaven instead.  (Metatron is basically the "head angel" and according to some opinions, whenever God is doing human-like things in the Bible it's really Metatron acting in His name).  Good Omens used this idea, putting Metatron and Satan at the head of the armies of Heaven and Hell, while God never shows up but is implied that He is subtly manipulating the whole story behind the scenes in humanity's favor.

Comment: One extrapolation you could make is that scripture is nothing but propaganda written  in favor of god and that, assuming that he (and the traditional setup of heaven/hell) exists, he is nowhere near as all-powerful as described. Then you might have the ingredients for an interesting story.

Comment: *"it should be doable to conquer Hell"* - there seems to be a gap in your logic.  Just because Demons are weaker than God, doesn't *necessarily* mean humans can beat them.  In DBZ terms:  if Humans have a power level of 1, and God's is a couple of quadrillion, then Demons might still be a trillion each....

Comment: Defeat God?  Yes, it can be done...  all you need is a babble fish

Comment: According to The Book of Job, God has the weakness that he can be baited into doing terrible things to one of his believers.

Comment: Hah hah! Chariots of Iron!  Judges 1, verse 16. https://biblehub.com/nkjv/judges/1.htm

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, I think most of the religion based stacks would be horrified by this question.

Comment: @Separatrix not looking for cynical/atheist answers calls for that horror, though

Comment: As a Christian, I take extreme exception to this question. -1 plus a flag.

Comment: I can't tell about Islam or Jewish tradition, but the Christian depiction of God is both vague and self-contradicting. That's the whole reason we have different Christian faiths. What you should do is make a question that goes like this: "Here's my world; there's a God figure who is based on this and this branch of the theology, and these and these are is powers - taking inspiration from religious texts of various Abrahamic faiths, what are his weaknesses?" That would make it into a world-building question, rather than a vaguely offensive theology question.

Comment: @thescribe-ReinstateMonica Both the Old and New Testament demonstrate that God can be prone to rash / impulsive actions when sufficiently provoked or enraged (Jesus and the Moneychangers or Abraham and Sodom - where a mere human *initially* helps him to calm down) - that's certainly a weakness, even if it's a hard one to exploit.  Flagging a question as "I don't like it" seems rather petty.

Comment: @Chronocidal, I agree, but I didn't expect much different when posing this question. The reason why I didn't put it in theology is because I hoped the Worldbuilding community would take it a little more amiably. It is a worldbuilding question; sorry everyone if I didn't make that clear.

I do wonder what it means that a supposedly omniscient being, aware of all time and space, is prone to make rash decisions when frustrated. You'd think nothing could surprise or irritate something like that.

Comment: @PastAndFuture It means *"I've given you free-will, am loath to take it away, and would prefer to stay relatively hands-off.  But, **Me**, you morons seem to delight in making the worst possible decisions."* - consider every parent who's ever had to resist the urge to rush in and take over when their child starts making doing things wrong, instead of letting them learn from their (many, ***many***) mistakes...  Not *surprising*, but waiting for that "Aha!" moment where they work out what to do (or not to do) can get *frustrating* - even knowing exactly when it will happen, *"why not sooner?"*

Comment: @Chronocidal That doesn't even relate to what I'm saying. This being allegedly knows everything that will happen before it even starts, without flaw. There is no "us doing things wrong." Whatever happened would not happen if this being didn't want it to, because all that happens exists as a result of him letting it. The flaw of the "free will" argument is that it suggests our decisions can evolve out from a point this god ordained. He's non-linear, as described. He wouldn't have caused beings to begin, but entire timelines start-to-finish. For him, it happens all in an instant.

Illogical.

Answer (score 7):

### Neither Heaven or Hell can be Conquered

Any story with humans physically killing angels or demons, isn't following canonical  Christian theology. Generally, they force God, demons, and angels into following the rules of this universe - giving them qualities such as mortality. To put it simply, if human weapons worked on demons, Christians would go everywhere armed.

Other stack exchange communities would be better able to answer the specifics about the spiritual warfare that many Christians believe is occurring, but it's less of physical war, and more of a spiritual war set on Earth with the fate of individual humans on the line.

From a gameplay perspective, this is less interesting then doomguy going to hell with is arsenal of weapons and blasting demons to oblivion, so most games do that instead.

Comment: *"Any story with humans physically fighting angels or demons, isn't following canonical Christian theology":* [Jacob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob) famously [wrestled with an angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_wrestling_with_the_angel) in Genesis 32:22–32. There are countless [paintings](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rembrandt_-_Jacob_Wrestling_with_the_Angel_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg) and illustrations of the fight. To say that a famous story from the book of Genesis is not following canonical Christian theology is . . . strange.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't the best word choice on my part. I changed it to killing.

Answer (score 4):

**No**

The whole point of God is that He is the maximally perfect being, and exists eternally. You cannot defeat that which precedes everything else. It’d be like a character in a book trying to kill the author.

The whole point of rebellion against God is that it is ultimately futile, just as fighting fate or casualty is.

The only way you could defeat God is essentially if He has some scenario where he’s weakening himself or using a fallible proxy (In which case it’s very questionable if you’re beating him, and not just entertaining him or defeating a Bronze Age tribe with chronic doubt issues)

Comment: I'd personally argue  that  in many religions the god is fallible in some way. That they are never perfect   if something is fallible you could defeat or convince it not  to be evil or whatever.

Comment: @neo flare fallible according to who? How would you convince a being who’s orders of magnitude older and more intelligent than you to stop doing something unless it already wants to do it? Philosophical omnipotence aside, it’d be like an ant arguing with Einstein

Comment: First thing that pops in my head is Zeus he is a  bloodly rapist. To the point that he is almost never portrayed in  a good light even by the Greeks. Being a god  will always put you in one perspective  so maybe the perspective of a "ant" would be interesting to a god of individuality since ants are all about group mentality Probably wont change its mind but would give it a new way of thinking

Comment: @neo flare I’d argue that Zeus and other Indo-European gods are substantially different from monotheistic ones. Monotheism brings certain philosophical arguments to the primacy of the God’s place in the universe, while the Greek Gods are clearly bested by mortals on several occasions. But I’d further venture that Zeus being a rapist is actually part of the point. As king of the gods he is supposed to be so beyond conventional norms and as the embodiment of Hellenistic masculinity he is given license to be that way (gross as it is, just remember the Ancient Greeks were institutional pedophiles)

Comment: I can see that. Though many bronze age religions even Christianity god is defeated or at least has some flaw. My answer pointed out that god was bested by iron chariots. He made a bet with the devil or some poor mans  life(note i haven't read the bible in the a long time). Monotheistic gods have flaws.

Comment: @neo flare I knew I’d see iron chariots come up. That’s a story that always gets thrown around but it’s not God who get’s bested, it’s the Israelites who fail because they’re afraid of them. (As I mentioned in my earlier post, Bronze Age tribes with chronic doubt). The same group of Israelites defeat the charioteers later. As for Job, I’d be hesitant to say that it was a weakness so much as showing that God’s priorities are radically different from humans

Comment: Meh fair enough. I'd argue that making a deal with the devil you fought and torturing a guy just to prove a point is a character flaw. Is job even rewarded for the stuff he went through i think he got a new wife?( once again haven't read in a while) .

Comment: @neo flare lmao I guess it really was a deal with the devil.  I always pictured it as some cosmic poker game.  Job gets a bunch of new stuff and wealth and new children, his wife survives the whole deal so she stays the same.

Comment: @neoflare it isn’t considered a deal with the devil in Christian writings. It is God’s attempt to teach the devil, who is, after all, another of God’s children. A deal implies an agreement between equals. This story is supposed to be read more as an exasperated parent indulging a teenager, knowing the teen will fail and finding the lesson worth the pain. (No one ever asks Job’s first wife and kids how they feel about this. I assume their afterlives were satisfactory to make this work.)

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for Jewish or Muslim, but in Orthodox Christianity God has one known "weakness" - **it's an absolute love for all its creation (humans included).**

This "weakness" can be exploited by evil minds to harm others (Satan does exactly this, *since God loves him too*), but this is a direct road to Hell - to eternal suffering.

It all means that all this "Hell conquers" would just stay there in Hell and join other sinners.

As for conquering Heavens - such a sinners would not be able to go there with such a goal. The only way to get to Heavens - is to ask (by pray and actions) and receive salvation from the God (in Christianity everybody are sinners - even saints). And with such a mechanism - there is no way of invasion possible.

If we somehow remove God - then both Hell and Heaven would also be removed (loose any sens) and, most probably, any existence. That what Satan is trying to do now - prove that God is wrong and He is not God, since His images (humans) are such bad persons (oversimplification - I know). This is a direct attack on Heavens (just don't let anyone go there), but it fails.

If we somehow *replace* God - then both Hell and Heaven would change it's meaning (and existence would also change). And that exactly what Lucifer tried to do (but failed). And the only "workable" plan to attack Heaven.

So to summarize weaknesses and "attack vectors":

1. God loves everybody and that can be and is exploited - but this will remove person (creature) far from God and Heaven.
2. It is possible to remove all people from Heaven by making them sinners (for example, persuade them to conquer the Hell) and thus proving that God is wrong (and thus might cease the existence)
3. God is absolute and defining. It means if somebody would become a God-like he/it would be able to replace Him and redefine everything.That seems to be impossible, but may be tried.

Comment: This answer is consistent with everything I have read about Christian and Jewish theology. I don’t have enough background in Muslim theology to comment.

Answer (score 1):

A common known paradox that’ll question whether a god is actually all powerful or all knowing is simple, like this, “ if god is all powerful, then can he make a object that he can’t lift”.

The first paradox Suggests that if god could create a object that he can’t lift, then he wouldn’t be all powerful, same goes with that if he can’t create such an object, then he can’t be all powerful. Now you question asks if god has a weakness, so we have to dig deeper. If god knew that man would make would eat from the tree of knowledge before he even created them, and asked Adam if he had or hadn’t would mean that he has doubts about said creation, making him, in a way, not perfect or at least not all knowing.

But I will add, that going into a more scientific Route, well, defeating a god would essentially be impossible, if we presume that a god is simply a higher dimensional being, then no matter how much we know about said strengths and possible weaknesses, we would still lose.

Hopefully this answers your question but it might not, this depends on you if it does or not.

Comment: Step 1:  God creates an object that he can't *currently* lift.  Step 2:  Using his all-powerfulness, he makes himself able to lift it.  The problem when dealing with "infinities", is that you can always go to "∞+1".  Ironically enough, it is *mathematicians* who formalised the rules of engagement for these scenarios, not philosophers.  (See also, [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes))

Answer (score 1):

God's one and only weakness is that he **cannot infringe a person's free will**. I can decide to commit a sin, or worship any other god than he (or no god at all), and he cannot snap his fingers and erase those thoughts from my mind. He can only punish me *after* I've already done it.

So if humanity does decide to conquer Heaven, that's their decision and God can't force them to change their minds. However, there's absolutely nothing stopping him from just flooding the world, or turning the rebelling humans into pillars of salt, or just saying "sod this" and bringing about the apocalypse. So while he does have a weakness, it's not really exploitable.

Answer (score 0):

> **God is fallible in the bible he makes mistakes**

"The LORD was with the men of Judah. They took possession of the hill country, but they were unable to drive the people from the plains, because they had chariots fitted with iron."

He made A bet with the devil. for some reason.  Many other things too

That is the  the only weakness is that good is not omnipotent in the bible or has a limited form of omnipotence . So maybe these warriors could use that to their advantage.

> **You could try other religions**

Many people in other religions achieve godhood  with acts of great sacrifice. Maybe the Universe itself is  some form of entity  that isn't a god but a law. It appreciates these acts of great sacrifice  so it may remove the current god and put a new one in.

> **Peace?**

The best way to defeat someone is to convince them that they were wrong and your side is right. Maybe god sees the error of his ways and decides not to be a D*ck.

Comment: Maybe set your story somewhere after the end of the Old Testament and the start of the New Testament. Or after the end of the Bible and before the start of the Koran. Both transitions, to me, show a deity evolving toward a less angry viewpoint (followers behavior notwithstanding).

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaking Revelation touches the subject of a war between Lucifer and god. Doubtful that such a creature would have started a war if there was no way for him to win, so perhaps an Archangel could be powerful enough to kill god.

> The general consensus is that, since there aren't any omnipotent or omniscient demons that Christians believe in, it should be doable to conquer Hell.

With that being said an alliance between earth and hell could be an option seeing demons are technically speaking (fallen) Angels so with the numbers advantage this alliance might seem favorable to the ruling class of hell.

The Dead Sea Scrolls should also provide some information about the war in question.